# How do I sort a column in google spreadsheets that recognizes 2 digit numbers with letters on the end sequentially?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I hope this makes sense. I have a spreadsheet that has a chromebook number column. It consist of numbers 1-500 and also has varying numbers with N or NS on the end. When I have the format on automatic, it sorts 1-500 sequentially but when the letters are added to the end it sorts by the first number as follows; 105N, 111N, **11N**, 122N, 136N, 144N, 202N, 215N, 255N, **25N** and so forth. As you can see it is putting the two digit numbers after three digit numbers. I would like to sort it so that it recognizing two digit numbers first then 3 digit numbers 11N, 25N, 105N, and so on. I tried changing format to plain text but then it has them all mixed together.
Thank you for any assistance. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORT({A1:A, REGEXEXTRACT(""&A1:A, "\d+")*1}, 2, 1),, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

If you need numeric-only entries to appear before numeric+alpha entries, here's a tweak to player0's nifty formula:

```
=INDEX(SORT({A1:A, REGEXEXTRACT(""&A1:A, "\d+")*1, A1:A&"A"}, 2, 1, 3, 1),, 1)
```